Connect to a ESP32-S3 via BLE
i am new to programming apps and connections. I made a arduino code and a flutter code, my problem is when i entered the app and try to connect to the board it shows me a error on my phone, Could not connect to the device
Connection Error

Could not connect to the device. Error: Platform Exception(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.re adAll(BluetoothSocket.java:987)

at android.bluetooth. BluetoothSocket.re

adInt(BluetoothSocket.java:1001) at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.co nnect(BluetoothSocket.java:527)

at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothseria 1.Bluetooth Connection.connect(Bluetooth Connection.java:57)

at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothseria 1.BluetoothConnection.connect(Bluetooth Connection.java:64)

at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothseria I.Flutter BluetoothSerial Plugin$FlutterBlue toothSerial Method CallHandler.lambda$o nMethodCall$4$io-github-edufolly- flutterbluetoothserial-Flutter Bluetooth Ser ialPlugin$Flutter Bluetooth Serial MethodC allHandler(Flutter BluetoothSerialPlugin.ja va:1007)

at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothseria I.Flutter Bluetooth Serial Plugin$FlutterBlue toothSerialMethod CallHandler$$External SyntheticLambda7.run(Unknownt

Here is the BluetoothConnectionPage:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'MyHomePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart'; 

class BluetoothConnectionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BluetoothConnectionPageState createState() => _BluetoothConnectionPageState();
}

class _BluetoothConnectionPageState extends State<BluetoothConnectionPage> {
  List<BluetoothDiscoveryResult> results = [];
  bool isDiscovering = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestBluetoothPermissions().then((_) {
      startDiscovery();
    });
  }

  Future<void> requestBluetoothPermissions() async {
    var statusScan = await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();
    var statusConnect = await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();

    print("Bluetooth Scan Permission: ${statusScan.isGranted}");
    print("Bluetooth Connect Permission: ${statusConnect.isGranted}");

    if (!statusScan.isGranted || !statusConnect.isGranted) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Permissions Required'),
          content: Text('Bluetooth scan and connect permissions are required to function.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void startDiscovery() {
    setState(() {
      results.clear();
      isDiscovering = true;
    });

    FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.startDiscovery().listen((r) {
      setState(() {
        if (!results.any((result) => result.device.address == r.device.address)) {
          results.add(r);
        }
      });
    }).onDone(() {
      setState(() {
        isDiscovering = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Connect to a Device"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(isDiscovering ? Icons.stop : Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              if (isDiscovering) {
                FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.cancelDiscovery();
              } else {
                startDiscovery();
              }
              setState(() {
                isDiscovering = !isDiscovering;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: results.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          BluetoothDiscoveryResult result = results[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(result.device.name ?? "Unknown device"),
            subtitle: Text(result.device.address),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.bluetooth),
            onTap: () => connectToDevice(result.device),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    try {
      BluetoothConnection connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(device.address);
      print('Connected to the device');
      connection.output.add(utf8.encode('PWD:2444\n'));
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MyHomePage(connection: connection),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Connection Error'),
            content: Text('Could not connect to the device. Error: $e'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Close'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
      print('Error connecting to device: $e');
    }
  }
}


And this is the arduino code
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>

// Define the servo motor object and pins
Servo servoMotor;
int brushlessPin = 2; // PWM pin connected to ESC
int reversePin = 5;   // Pin to control direction (forward/reverse)
int servoPin = 9;     // PWM pin connected to the servo motor

// BLE Service and Characteristic UUIDs
const char* serviceUUID = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789ABC";
const char* speedCharacteristicUUID = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789ABD";
const char* directionCharacteristicUUID = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789ABE";
const char* passwordCharacteristicUUID = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789AAF";

BLEService rcCarService(serviceUUID);
BLEIntCharacteristic speedCharacteristic(speedCharacteristicUUID, BLERead | BLEWrite);
BLEIntCharacteristic directionCharacteristic(directionCharacteristicUUID, BLERead | BLEWrite);
BLEStringCharacteristic passwordCharacteristic(passwordCharacteristicUUID, BLERead | BLEWrite, 10); // Length is 10 chars

bool isAuthenticated = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing servos and pins...");
  servoMotor.setPeriodHertz(50); // Standard 50 Hz servo
  servoMotor.attach(servoPin, 500, 2400); // Attach servo motor to pin

  pinMode(brushlessPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(reversePin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(reversePin, LOW); // Initialize direction as forward
  analogWrite(brushlessPin, 0); // Stop the motor initially

  Serial.println("Starting delayed BLE initialization...");
  delay(5000); // Delay for 5 seconds before initializing BLE to simulate post-reset conditions

  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to start BLE!");
    while (1); // Hang if BLE initialization fails
  } else {
    Serial.println("BLE initialized successfully.");
  }

  BLE.setLocalName("RC Car BLE");
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(rcCarService);

  Serial.println("Adding characteristics...");
  rcCarService.addCharacteristic(speedCharacteristic);
  rcCarService.addCharacteristic(directionCharacteristic);
  rcCarService.addCharacteristic(passwordCharacteristic);

  BLE.addService(rcCarService);

  speedCharacteristic.writeValue(0);
  directionCharacteristic.writeValue(90);
  passwordCharacteristic.writeValue("");

  BLE.advertise();
  Serial.println("BLE is now advertising. Ready to connect.");
}

void loop() {
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();

  if (central) {
    Serial.println("Connected to central device.");
    while (central.connected()) {
      if (passwordCharacteristic.written()) {
        if (passwordCharacteristic.value() == "2444") {
          isAuthenticated = true;
          Serial.println("Authenticated successfully.");
        } else {
          Serial.println("Authentication failed.");
          isAuthenticated = false;
        }
      }

      if (isAuthenticated) {
        if (speedCharacteristic.written()) {
          int speed = speedCharacteristic.value();
          controlSpeed(speed);
        }
        if (directionCharacteristic.written()) {
          int direction = directionCharacteristic.value();
          servoMotor.write(direction);
        }
      }
    }
    isAuthenticated = false;
    Serial.println("Central device disconnected.");
  }
}

void controlSpeed(int speed) {
  bool reverse = (speed < 0);
  digitalWrite(reversePin, reverse ? HIGH : LOW);
  analogWrite(brushlessPin, abs(speed));
}


This is a project for university, and I'm trying to achive a BLE connection and to be protected with a password when you try to connect, between an android app made with flutter, and an arduino esp32-s3, the arduino will go in a 3d printed car, with an servo motor and a brushless motor, plus some led's, to be honest I never used flutter to create an app, and the arduino projects I made are very simple, this is far from my comfort zone, and I am stuck now.
I tried finding something on the internet but I found nothing, asked chat gpt cause a lot of the code is made with help from it, and it does not find a solution either.

You are using flutter_bluetooth_serial, which is a package for Bluetooth Serial (also called Bluetooth Classic). But you want BLE, so you need something like flutter_blue_plus. Since you already finished the code for your Arduino you can already test it using a generic BLE exploration tool such as nRF Connect

thanks, i'll try that, and if i got a problem i'll comment here

Ok so i encountered this error now:
Following this change, your app will not be available to users running Android SDKs below 21. │
Consider searching for a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the     │
Android SDK instead.
For more information, see:
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration

Ok, where is the problem? Do you need to support an Android SDK below 21? Android SDK 21 is Version 5.0, not only did the BLE API change significantly with this version, there are probably not many users still using Android 5.0

ok so that's what is reffering too, cause it shows and would not allow me to debug it, and it was connected to my phone which has an android 14, ok, thanks a lot, you are great
